# Whats wrong in the document composition?

Tags: longtable, parbox

I generate document automatically, and got the error `! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.` I know this error, but i can't understand the reason in my case.
Here is minimum example:

```
    \documentclass{report}
        \usepackage{fancybox,fancyhdr}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
        \usepackage{fixltx2e}
        \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
        \usepackage[left=72pt,right=72pt, top=72pt,bottom=72pt,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
        \usepackage{array}
        \usepackage{longtable}
        \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
        \newcolumntype{R}[2]{>{\raggedleft \arraybackslash \hspace{0pt}}{#2}{#1}}
        \newcolumntype{L}[2]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}{#2}{#1}}
        \newcolumntype{C}[2]{>{\center\arraybackslash}{#2}{#1}}
    \fancyhead[C]{\noindent\sbox{0}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\noindent\begin{longtable}{c}Text\end{longtable}}}
        \ifdim\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0<14pt
        \dp0\dimexpr14pt-\ht0\fi
        \makebox{\usebox{0}}\\}\begin{document}
        \pagestyle{fancy}
        \noindent\sbox{0}{\parbox{\textwidth}{
    \noindent\begin{longtable}{L{\textwidth}{p}}list 
    \begin{itemize}
    \item item
    \end{itemize}
    \end{longtable}}}
        \ifdim\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0<240.44036697248pt
        \dp0\dimexpr240.44036697248pt-\ht0\fi
        \makebox{\usebox{0}}\\
    \noindent\begin{longtable}{L{450mm}{p}}Love\\\end{longtable}
    \begin{longtable}{p{90mm}R{40mm}{p}rc}
                Own party & &  Unscored \\ [10pt]
                Own parties & & & \\ [10pt]
            Entity that is contracting on our behalf \\{Which of our own parties is contracting on our behalf?}&{Unknown}&Unscored& \\ [10pt]
        Reference name \\ {Reference name used to refer to the own party}&{Unknown}&Unscored& \\ [10pt]
        \end{longtable}

        \begin{longtable}{p{90mm}R{40mm}{p}rc}
                Counterparties & &  Unscored \\ [10pt] 
                Counterparty & & & \\ [10pt]
        Reference name \\{Reference name used to refer to the counterparty}&{Unknown}&Unscored& \\ [10pt] 
        Counterparty identity\\{None provided}&{Unknown}&Unscored& \\[10pt] 
        Whether we are contracting with a company, branch, individual or some other kind of entity? \\ {The type of entity you are planning to contract with is really important when deciding whether the deal is appropriate. For example, you can hold a company to account for most contract terms it agrees to. But the same is not true when you are dealing with an individual - they might be able to get out of these terms even if they had signed up to them. }&{Unknown}&Unscored& \\[10pt]
Name of counterparty \\ {None provided}&{Unknown}&Unscored& \\[10pt]
       \end{longtable}
       \end{document}
```

The error dissappear when i remove part of text (`For example, you can hold a company` ... ) or when i remove parbox from header, or when i remove parbox from the first longtable..... i can't understand  why it happens??? How to fix the error without removing parts of the document?

Can you please explain me, whats wrong in this case?.

Update (due to comments): if the last table looks so (without last `\\`) still it doesn't work after small TEXT changes:

```
\begin{longtable}{p{90mm}R{40mm}{p}rc}
                Counterparties & &  Unscored \\ \\ 
                Counterparty & & & \\ \\
        Reference name \\{Reference name used to refer to the counterparty}&{Unknown}&Unscored& \\ \\ 
        Counterparty identity\\{None provided}&{Unknown}&Unscored& \\ \\ 
        Whether we are contracting with a company, branch, individual or some other kind of entity? \\ {The type of entity you are planning to contract with is really important when deciding whether the deal is appropriate. For example, you can hold a company to account for most contract terms it agrees to. But the same is not true when you are dealing with an individual - they might be able to get out of these terms even if they had signed up to them. }&{Unknown}&Unscored& \\ \\ 
Name of counterparty \\ {None provided}&{Unknown}&Unscored& \\ 
       \end{longtable}
       \end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico it doesn't help. I wonder why to fix this error i don't need to change longtables with the error - but i need only to remove on of neighbor components. I mean the real error is not on the line that compiler points.

Comment: Your error disappears by removing the last `\\ ` in the last table.

Comment: @TeXnician it works, untill i add some changes to the text part: see the update in the question. The same table - just text content added - and broken again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `\\ \\`. if you need some more space then use something like `\\[10pt]` which adds 10pt after the line. And, of course, in your header definition with `\fancyhead` use `tabular` and _ not_ `longtable`.

Comment: i replaced all as you said - it makes no sence ( the same error

Comment: edit your code that it shows the changes. I have no problem

Comment: done. you can see a code with your changes. I just put some additional text in the last table - and again it doesn't work

Comment: in your header definition with `\fancyhead`  use `tabular` and _ not_ `longtable`

Comment: that's it!!! thank you a lot!!! please add this comment to the answer.